# How can I find records where a date is within the current month using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple rails app that is like an event system which has a `start_at` field and an `end_at` field. I want to be able to display the events whose `start_at` month fall at this present month. I defined a scope for this like below:

```
scope :this_months_event, lamda{where("start_at = ?" Time.zone.now.month)}
```

Whenever I try this out in my console window I get an empty array. I observed that the month of the `start_at` field is not being fetched so it cannot find the `start_at` month, so it returns empty instead.

Does anyone know a good way to do this or how can I pass the `start_at` month so that when I call `Event.this_months_event`, I get all the events for this present month and if possible a scope to fetch past events and another to fetch present events.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your condition says that start_at should be exactly the value of Time.zone.now.month, which, as of this writing is 8. You want to compare start_at with the beginning and end of the month:

```
scope :this_months_event, lambda { where("start_at >= ? AND start_at <= ?", 
  Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now.end_of_month) }
```

Comment: You would need a `lambda` there, otherwise your code might behave unexpectedly in production, where classes are cached.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `start_at` and `end_at` are datetimes? If so, you'll need to do something slightly more sophisticated:

```
scope :this_months_event, lambda { where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_at)) = ?", Time.zone.now.month) }
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: Nice, didn't know about extract month, but… this scope would find events from previous (and coming) years, in the same calendar month.

Comment: your `FROM` is like a postgresql but what of for sqlite. cos i just tried it out and it does not work for sqlite

Comment: Yeah, this code is neither correct or portable, but the EXTRACT stuff can be very useful.